# Can I use PXAccumulator attribute not only in processing pages

Tags: erp, acumatica

Currently I read T200 manual. It describes PXAcccumulator attribute. Who knows, can I use PXAccumulator attributes not only in processing pages, but for example in data entry pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You totally can. `PXAccumulator` is functional in any type of page - actually there is no difference between the processing graphs and any other ones in the context of the `PXAccumulator` usage.

However, most of the scenarios when this attribute is useful do involve processing operations and thus fall into the processing pages category - that's why the corresponding part of the course is chosen to explain `PXAccumulator`.

If you end up using the attribute elsewhere do bear in mind that the operations performed by the `PXAccumulator` are executed when the graph is persisted. When we speak of processing pages and operations, *the decision on when to save state* to the database is made by the programmer, while in case of data entry pages the user decides *when and how many times* to press the Save button. Still, with some care it is not too difficult to make use of `PXAccumulator` anywhere - even though it's not always a good idea.